# "react" was conflicted between "package.json PROBLEM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A morning my react code is well working but after running app on night it is showing error , i cannot find which type of error occur , and not found any type of solution ,help me for solving my error on react :

[eslint] Plugin [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd2jX.jpg) » eslint-config-react-app » D:\LP\Web Development course\REact Tutorials\React\livecovidreports\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » D:\LP\Web Development course\React Tutorials\React\livecovidreports\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

Comment: Just post the error message as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.